# Write JSON To Console

Tags: c#, json, console-application

I am new to `JSON` and tryin to add a `JSON` string then write it to console.  Any attempt I make to write the below message and not what I expected

> System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader

This is how I tried to write, is this the proper way?

```
private void WriteToConsole ()
{
    var jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"{ ""Security"": { ""UsernameToken"": { ""Username"": ""belljeantest"", ""Password"": ""r@b!e$"" } }"), new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
    Console.WriteLine(jsonReader);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You can't write the reader directly, JsonReader creates a https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will convert it into an XDocument which you then need to read/use accordingly.

```
private void WriteToConsole ()
{
    var jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"{ ""Security"": { ""UsernameToken"": { ""Username"": ""belljeantest"", ""Password"": ""r@b!e$"" } }"), new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
    var xml = XDocument.Load(jsonReader);
    Console.Write(xml);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The above will print the whole XML file.  You can query this using LINQ. For more on XDocument: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx